# Must apply database normalization when have a lot  more insertions than queries?

Tags: database, postgresql, normalization

I did a webcrawler and it inserts various pages and links in the database. At the moment, the domain of the URL crawled is a attribute in the page and in the links table.

I'm thinking about creating a table for the domains, but I fear that this slow the insertion.

At the moment, I have 1,200,000 links downloaded and 70,000 pages in database and this will increase.

What is the better solution to do? Create the domain table? Create a index in the domain attribute(it's a varchar)?

PS: A other program that I developing will do queries in this database.

Comment: I think more information about queries is needed. do you have performance problems? why you want to add an index? why not use an ORM? is your webcrawler inserting data with queries?

Comment: What is ORM? At the moment, no problem with queries because I don't started the another software that will make queries, but it will use often the domain attribute in these tables (page, link.)

Comment: My webcrawler is inserting data with queries. There are another ways to insert the data in the database?

Comment: ORM == 'Object Relational Mapper', they're used to present an OO interface to tables and they're probably the last thing you want to be dealing with if you're doing bulk operations and you're concerned about performance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you have two tables: "links" and "pages". You say nothing about the fields within those tables. More information would be nice.

Anyhow, a fully normalized database tends to erode the performance. I would suggest keeping the domains as attribute in both tables. A little redundancy might improve your performance.

One more advice, instead of having one database, you might want to have two: one for inserts and updates only; and the other one for read-only access(selects).

In the first DB remove all indexes and constrains. This will give you fast insert/update operations.

In the read-only DB, design indexes properly to make the retrieval operations faster.

Of course, you need to synchronize the two databases somehow. This might require some extra coding.

Comment: The others attributes are relative to the downloaded page and are corrects. The redundancy is in the domain and the attributes relatives to it like host and country.

Comment: I liked this idea of two databases, but I like to know the opnions of the others about this idea and the the implementation. I think that I have one database for the robot and another for the data mining. The first will have more inserts and updates, but a bit of query to retrieve the links, and the other more queries.

Comment: Create another schema or another database?

Comment: Yes, one database for the robot and other one for data mining. I would suggest two databases, which you can deploy even in different servers if nodded.

Comment: Sorry...I meant " if needed." :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do some playing around to see what kind of results you get from the different methods.  How many different domains do you have?

Keep in mind that if you create an index on the domain attribute it will actually slow down your inserts.  Indexes are good for improving select performance but they slow down update/delete/insert operations because it is an extra thing that needs to get updated.

I would personally go the domains in a separate table if there are a relatively small number.

Comment: No, there a lot of domains. The number of different domains can exceed the million mark.

Comment: Interesting, so of the 1.2 million rows 1 million have distinct domains?  If that is the case I would probably stick with the single table and no indexes at all.  Are you experiencing performance problems currently?

Comment: No, at the moment, there no more than 50,000 differents domains (I'm restoring the database, I will provide the correct number), but with the time, the number of domains will increase

Comment: The performance problem I'm having is due to another thing (urls set like unique, but I guess that this deserves another question.)

Comment: 9942 domains on page, 87651 domains on link.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't see why you wouldn't normalize**.
Certainly, this will affect, slightly, the performance of the insertions, but I would hope that the bottleneck (and or the throttling) would be at the level of the page dowloads.  If it were not the case, this would indicate that you're ***whacking the h' out of the Internet***! ;-)
Typical crawlers [outside of these used by big SEs of course], even when run on multiple threads and even on several machines only produce, in total and sustained fashion, a few dozen pages per second, which is well below the capability of most DBMS servers, even with a bit of contention.

Also one would expect the domains table to be relatively small and accessed frequently, mostly reading, and hence generally cached.

I would only consider denormalization and other tricks in the case of

- much higher sustained insertion rate
- bigger database (say, if it is expected to grow in above, 100 million rows).

Comment: I'm respecting the robots.txt and using a delay of 20 seconds to visit each domain again. And due to my low bandwith and computer, I have at maximum, 4 pages per second.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database design is like so:

```
Page: 
Id | URL

Link:
Id | Page_Id | URL
```

If there is a lot of re-use of URLs (like for TVTropes), I would most likely reformat the design to:

```
Domain:
Id | URL

Page:
Id | URL_Id

Link:
Id | Page_Id | URL_Id
```

When you go to do your datamining, I'd then recommend an index on URL, in addition to all the usual ones.

If space is becoming an issue (more than insert or retrieval times), and there are numerous levels to your URLs (deep folder structures), you could try this -

```
Domain:
Id | Parent_Id | URL_Part

Page:
Id | URL_Id

Link:
Id | Page_Id | URL_Id
```

This will of course need a recursive query to assemble the URL, but the datamining prospects for this are immense.  Without knowing more about your actual design (and your intended use), there's not a lot more I can really propse, though.